# Extract substring between special characters in a string

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to extract account name and region from AWS ARN(Amazon resource number)for a postgres RDS instance and pass it to another script. Ex for ARN:

```
arn:aws:rds:eu-central-1:123456789777:db:testdb
```

In above example, I am trying to extract `region= eu-central-1` and `accountnumber= 123456789777`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `SPLIT_PART` here:

```
with cte AS (
    select 'arn:aws:rds:eu-central-1:123456789777:db:testdb'::text as arn
)

select
    split_part(arn, ':', 4) as region,
    split_part(arn, ':', 5) as account_no
from cte;
```

[image]

### Demo